# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'split') with VSCode Copilot

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-copilot

I'm trying to ask Copilot to do something, anything programming, and yet I keep getting the answer:

Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'split')

Why?

Comment: Is this in a file or in Chat?

Comment: i see it in the chat and i must start a new chat after that error